# Copy active worksheet to new worksheet while making cell adjustments

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet

I'm looking for a VBA to copy an active worksheet to a new worksheet, I would like the VBA to copy the page layout as well from active sheet. As well if cell O3 could be increased by 1 for each worksheet. Not sure if possible but if the worksheet would rename itself to what ever corresponds in Cell O2

I'm currently using the following code, this will copy active worksheet to new work sheet but it doesn't keep my formatting (Margins, Scaling)

```
Sub Macro1()
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Worksheets.Add after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

I made some adjustments to the following

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim sheetToCopy As Worksheet, newSheet As Worksheet
    Set sheetToCopy = ActiveSheet
    sheetToCopy.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Set newSheet = Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    newSheet.Range("O2").Value = newSheet.Range("O2").Value + 1
    newSheet.Range("O3").Value = newSheet.Range("O3").Value + 1
End Sub
```

since O2 is ever changing I would want to keep O2 as the Worksheet name. As well I keep getting a pop up about "The name 'Group6' already exist. click yes to use that version of the name..."

How would I get this to stop this dialog box from popping up?

Comment: I got some questions: 1. Do you copy always the same worksheet, or any? 2. Would you please post the formulas or values in Cells `O2` and `O3`. 3. When are you getting this pop up? It seems to be due to the name of the worksheet already taken, but you are not showing the code used to rename the worksheet. Also this name `Group6` does not seems to be coming as the result of the formula in `O2`.

Comment: This workbook is a invoice book for jobs that go for a month at a time.  There's no formulas in cell O2 pr O3, The value in O2 is the current date, while the value in O3 is an invoice number. The workbook is set up at the start of the job, the worksheet name is sheet 1 and every day I need to change the name to the date which is why I would like it linked to cell O2.  Every time I click the next day button I received the error group6 It's more so a Hassel for guys in the field.

Comment: ok so the copies are always done from "sheet 1". Now do you want in the new sheet the value of cell O2 to be the actual date when the "next day" button is clicked or to be the date in the "sheet 1" +1. the difference is that there could be days when the next button is just not used, then the guys in the field do it for several days in one go, rather than doing it concurrently.

Comment: As regards the popup for the name `Group6` I don't see anything in the code sample that could relate to that. The message looks like the one generated when trying to rename a worksheet with the name of an existing one, but from your comments the name of the new worksheet is the date of the invoice which is all numeric. I guess you still have to add to your question the part of the code related to that. Now that brings another question what should happen if the user attempts to create an invoice that already exist.

Comment: Whats' the status? Have you tried any of the answers provided?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim sheetToCopy as Worksheet, newSheet as Worksheet
    Set sheetToCopy = ActiveSheet

    '## Copy to a new sheet
    sheetToCopy.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

    Set newSheet = Sheets(Sheets.Count)

    '## Name the new sheet based on O2 in the original sheet
    '   NOTE: This will fail if a sheet of this name already exists.
    newSheet.Name = sheetToCopy.Range("O2").Value
    '## Increment the value in O3 on the new sheet
    newSheet.Range("O3").Value = newSheet.Range("O3").Value + 1
End Sub
```

Comment: It sounds like you might have to put the new value into O3 and *then* get a new worksheet name from O2; e.g. O2 contains a formula that depends upon the value in O3.

Answer (score 0):

This code includes:

Two options to update the date of the new invoice

1. Using the actual date of the computer (relies on the date of the computer to stay updated) *(!)*
2. Uses the Next Day as per Template Worksheet

Two Options on dealing with existing Invoice for the date

1. Deletes existing invoice, keeps new one *(!)*
2. Renames existing invoice by adding a time stamp to the name, keeps both.

*(!) These options are commented in the code if you want to use any of them uncomment it and delete\comment the 2nd option*

```
Sub NewInvoice_Add()
Dim WshSrc As Worksheet
Dim WshTrg As Worksheet
Dim sDate As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    With ThisWorkbook

        Rem Set Source Worksheet
        Set WshSrc = .Sheets("Sheet 1")

        Rem Set Date & Last Invoice Number in Source Worksheet
        With WshSrc
                'Option 1. Use Actual Date - Relays on date of the computer to be updated
                '.Range("O2").Value = Date

                'Option 2. Use Next Day as per Template Worksheet
                .Range("O2").Value = .Range("O2").Value2 + 1

            sDate = Format(.Range("O2").Value2, "dd-mm-yyyy")   ' Adjust date format as required
            .Range("O3").Value = .Range("O3").Value2 + 1
        End With

        Rem Create New Invoice from Source Worksheet
        WshSrc.Copy After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
        Set WshTrg = .Sheets(.Sheets.Count)

        'Dealing with existing worksheet for the date

            'Option 1. Deleting it
            'On Error Resume Next
            '.Sheets(sDate).Delete
            'On Error GoTo 0

            'Option 2. Renaming it
            On Error Resume Next
            .Sheets(sDate).Name = sDate & Format(Now, "_HHMM")
            On Error GoTo 0

        Rem Name New Worksheet
        WshTrg.Name = sDate

    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```